# Javascript: Parse JSON object while preserving order of numeric keys

Tags: javascript, json, insertion-order

I'm trying to display some JSON data in the browser which comes from a Python application, this data contains objects with numerical keys which order must be preserved when parsed in Javascript.
Unfortunately, Javascript does not keep the order of object keys, instead sorting numerical keys in ascending order.

[image: JSON tree view]

The purpose of this is to display events from said JSON data in a human-readable manner, so their order is important. Other questions in a similar vein suggest wrapping every object in an array but this would mean sacrificing human-readability and would force modification of the Python application, which dictionaries have no issue maintaining insertion order.

I'm aware of the [Map class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map) in Javascript which allows for a dictionary-like structure while preserving insertion order in all cases. Is there a way to make `JSON.parse` output objects to Maps? Is there some third-party library I should look into?

Comment: asking for libraries is ot.

Comment: An object structure described in JSON is unordered. If the API requires a fixed order, they should be using an array. One option would be to write your own JSON parser, and to  use a callback function to track key order in an array.

Comment: If each of the `models` has one object that has one object, and that object's key is the order required, you can "move it up" one level, and that would give you the order - assuming you want `5412....` before `8618...` as seen in your image.
If that's what you want - I can help, otherwise, as @slappy said, make the Python application send the `models` as an Array.

Comment: I was kinda hoping you could do this with the reviver, but it turns out you cannot. I guess using a custom json parsing libary is your only choice.

Comment: But yes, the proper solution is to fix your Python code that generates the JSON, as JSON objects are defined to be unordered so you really shouldn't be using them if order is important (and cannot be reconstructed in some other way).

Comment: Discussed here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41702800/convert-json-to-array-map